# Phrase for curious attraction

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I have a sentence that I would like to complete. The sentence is:

> "I was drawn to this moving creature like _______ "

Let's say the moving creature is an insect I had never seen before.

I am searching for a phrase that describes curious attraction or just attraction. All I could come up with right now are: like moon to the earth, and like a kitten to a ball of wool. Any suggestions people?

Comment: Like a magnet, would that work?

Comment: moving creature: that moves, or moving creature: that moves you (emotionally). Like Alice at the Mad Hatter's tea party. There's always something in Lewis Caroll.  Like the crew drawn to hunting the snark. There is no better author from whom to draw quirky inspiration than this paragon.

Comment: '... like a fly to manure' is a fixed phrase (coinings would be off-topic as not reflecting established usage), but doesn't work well here.

Comment: @Lambie moving creature: that moves (physically). And sorry, this may be a mortal sin but I haven't read Lewis Caroll yet. So I can't draw an inspiration from his work.

Comment: I still haven't got a good answer, people.

Answer (score 1):

> **[like a moth to a flame](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+moths+to+a+flame)** (idioms.thefreedictionary.com):

- If a person is attracted to someone or something like a moth to a
  flame, they are strongly attracted to them.

> **Note:** This expression is very variable. For example, you can talk
>   about **moths around a flame**, or replace **flame** with **candle**.
>
> *Men flock around her like moths around a flame.*
>
> (Collins COBUILD Idioms Dictionary)

- **With intense and immediate interest.**

> *Whenever I park my Ferrari, there's inevitably someone who wants to come gawk at it, like a moth to a flame.*
>
> (Farlex Dictionary of Idioms)

Comment: Thanks Mahmud. But I feel the phrase moth to a flame describes a relationship that is destructive to one of the parties involved. And that is not the sentiment I want my sentence to carry.

Comment: @Breamhall , I don't think the idiom has such a connotation. See the example sentences from the cited dictionaries. Both the sentences do not indicate a 'destructive relation', whereas they show the *attraction* and *curiosity* in the exact sense.

Comment: It's certainly got that connotation. In fact, [PhraseFinder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/232050.html) includes this in the denotation: 'Irresistably and dangerously attracted to something or someone'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/like_a_moth_to_the_flame) has a similar definition, but it doesn’t have connotations of danger, only irresistibility. I agree with mahmud koya.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And I consider Oxford more authoritative than “PhraseFinder.”